# visual studioc++ array size in struct is too long

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, struct

I am currently doing an assignment for my beginner C++ course, the chapter is on structs. I am using visual studio so I am can't do anything fancy for dynamic array's (i.e. no vector's etc.).

The part of the homework I am having trouble with is reading a file with some spaces at the end of the file. Since I am using filename.eof() it is reading the blanks and recording that data. I tried doing cin.ignore(xxxxx, '\n'), however that did not work. The my current out put is the data I want but a row of garbage. How do I get rid of the garbage?

a) A function to read the data into the array. You can use the attached file named soccer-1.txt to test your code. It also goes without saying that your code must work with any input data file. Of course, for testing, use your file to avoid entering data while testing. The name of the data file must always be entered by the user (do not hard code a file name). Also, check to make sure that the given input data file exists. If the file does not exist, issue an error message to alert the user about the invalid file name. Make sure to ask the user again for the name of another file. However, terminate the program after the user has entered an incorrect file name for a total of 3 times. NOTE: the data file name can be input inside the function.

The text file looks like this:
"

```
Duckey E Donald forward 8 2 21
Goof B Goofy defense 12 0 82
Brave A Balto goalkeeper 0 0 5
Snow W White defense 1 2 3
Alice I Wonderful midfield 1 5 15
Samina S Akthar right_defense 1 2 7
Simba P Green left_back 7 3 28
**************WHITESPACE****************************
**************WHITESPACE****************************
```

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int subSize = 100;

//struct to store nameInfo
struct nameInfo
{
    string fName;
    char middleInitial;
    string lName;
};


//struct to store playerInfo
struct playerInfo
{
    nameInfo name;

    string postion;

    int goals;
    int penalties;
    int jersey;
};

int getData(playerInfo matrix[]);
void displayData(playerInfo matrix[], int arraySize);

int main()
{

    playerInfo p;
    playerInfo playerArray[subSize];
    int arraySize;
    int userSelection;
    string searchTerm;


    arraySize = getData(playerArray);

    cout << arraySize << " records found." << endl << endl;



    displayData(playerArray, arraySize); //call to display all data
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

//function to read the data into the array
int getData(playerInfo matrix[])
{
    ifstream infile;

    string fileName;
    int i = 0;          //counter to hold array row length
    int k = 0;          //counter for file input
    int x = 0;          //counter for user input


    cout << "Enter the file name (e.g. soccer-1.txt): ";
    getline(cin, fileName);
    cout << endl;

    infile.open(fileName.c_str());

    //checks if file exists
    //ask the user again for the name of another file
    //loop returns -1 after 3 failed attempts to enter a file
    while (!infile)
    {
        k++;

        cout << "After attempt " << k
            << " input file not opened." << endl;

        cout << "Attempt " << k + 1 << ", enter the file name (e.g. soccer.txt): ";
        getline(cin, fileName);
        cout << endl;

        infile.open(fileName.c_str());


        cout << endl;
        if (k == 2) //terminate program at 2 because entered validation loop
        {           //after first attempt
            cout << "Terminating program.";
            return -1;
        }
    }

    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        infile >> matrix[i].name.fName >> matrix[i].name.middleInitial
            >> matrix[i].name.lName >> matrix[i].postion
            >> matrix[i].goals >> matrix[i].penalties
            >> matrix[i].jersey;

        i++; //holds size of array

    }

    infile.close();
    return i;

}


void displayData(playerInfo matrix[], int arraySize)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < arraySize; y++)
    {
        //display format:
        //Duckey.(E)Donald:8 2 21 – forward
        cout << matrix[y].name.fName
            << ".(" << matrix[y].name.middleInitial << ")"
            << matrix[y].name.lName << ":" << matrix[y].goals << " "
            << matrix[y].penalties << " " << matrix[y].jersey
            << " - " << matrix[y].postion << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should be able to use `std::vector` with Visual Studio - you're using `std::string` and `std::cout` after all! Unless it's a restriction from your teachers, it's a solid rule of thumb that a `std::vector` is preferable to a raw array.

Comment: Also, general good practice, use a descriptive variable name instead of a comment. For instance, `int playerArraySize;` is clearer than `int i; // player array size`

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is where you can apply a change:

```
while (!infile.eof()) {
  infile >> matrix[i].name.fName >> matrix[i].name.middleInitial >>
      matrix[i].name.lName >> matrix[i].postion >> matrix[i].goals >>
      matrix[i].penalties >> matrix[i].jersey;

  i++; // holds size of array
}
```

Read to a string, or a set of strings, instead of straight to the container. That way you can check they're valid (i.e. not blank) before copying to the `matrix` container.